# React router v6 optional paramaeter in the middle

Tags: reactjs, react-router

We are building a web application where different users have different roles.
Now we are facing a situation with react router that we cant seem to figure out

We have a url `page/:contractor/:site`
but there is a speacial case for contractor type user `page/:site` where contractor is extracted from the user data. `:contractor` cannot be in the URL as this might open up a potentsial way to spy on others.

```
<Route path="page">
  <Route index element={element} />
  <Route path=":contractor" >
    <Route index element={element2} />
    <Route path=":site" >
      <Route index element={element3} />
      <Route path=":parameter" element={element4} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Also the elements intrnaly use the useParams() hook to get the url parameters and then set filter based on those. And the routes are all protected via authentication and rolebased checks. The `element` internaly does also a rolebased check currently, where it shows either a table or renders the same contents ans element2.

Is there a way to work with the current route structure? Or should i create 2 routes for essentialy same elements and add some HOC aroudn them to handle the useParams mess that this is gona cause.

Comment: Why would the frontend, even with tinkering be able to spy on others? All validation should be (also) on the server, never trust the client.

Comment: As it is right now for stupid reasons beyond us. We dont have any way to check the contractor matchup on the server side.

Comment: Are `"/page/:site"` and `"/page/:contractor/:site"` supposed to be sibling routes, i.e. you can only match one or the other? It's a bit unclear what you are asking for and the provide routing snippet doesn't quite agree with the description in the question. I also do see any optional parameters, but perhaps this is what you mean by trying to match either of the two routes I asked about.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes you should be able to only match on or the other. They are roughly the same, it just for the longer case there exists a intermediate element that for shorter case does not exist. THe example provided is what we currently have.

Comment: How do you differentiate what component you want to render when the path can match either `"/page/:contractor"` or `"/page/:site"`? Is this the real issue you are asking for help with? I also agree with @Undo's comment regarding the "leaking" of data that should be protected. Seem s like a much larger issue than just route matching.

Comment: We have potectedRoute component that does role check and then redirects based on the results. THat can be used as the splitting point. But anything else would be nice if no component duplication is required. And the "leaking", its for stupid reason we cant change or fix for the time being, dont overthink the server side.